# SQL PIVOT 2 Columns and repeat for multiples - HEAD SCRATCHER

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot, sql-server-2016

I am having a HECK of a time trying to pivot some data & am wondering if anyone has an idea that would solve this!

I have tried dynamic pivots, but I run out of columns fast.

I have tried multiple pivots and joining them, but that is very clunky.

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Visits
(
  SourceID varchar(32), 
  VisitID varchar(32), 
  EpisodeDate varchar(9),
  EpisodeUrnID int, 
  SortOrder int, 
  ProcID char(7)
);

INSERT dbo.Visits
  (SourceID,VisitID,EpisodeDate,EpisodeUrnID,SortOrder,ProcID) 
VALUES
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','20-May-19',1,1,'5A1955Z'),
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','20-May-19',1,2,'0BH17EZ'),
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','24-May-19',2,1,'03HY32Z'),
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','6-Jun-19' ,3,1,'03HY32Z'),
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','21-May-19',4,1,'02HV33Z'),
('SKREE','B20190531064919932','21-May-19',4,2,'B548ZZA'),
('SKREE','B20210530154407871','30-May-21',1,1,'0DTJ4ZZ'),
('SKREE','B20210530154407871','3-Jun-21' ,2,1,'0W9G40Z'),
('SKREE','B20210530154407871','3-Jun-21' ,2,2,'0WJG4ZZ'),
('SKREE','B20210530154407871','7-Jun-21' ,3,1,'02HV33Z'),
('SKREE','B20210530154407871','7-Jun-21' ,3,2,'B548ZZA');
```

Basically, for every VisitID, there are multiple EpisodeUrnIds, which can have multiple SortOrders and I need to list the EpisodeDate and ProcID of each on the same row.

I have analyzed our tables and one VisitID can have up to 40 EpisodeUrnIDs (so far), with each having up to 20 SortOrders (so far).

My goal is to get it to look like this (I used the first VisitID only in this example):

```
SourceID|VisitID|EpisodeDate|ProcID|EpisodeDate|ProcID|EpisodeDate|ProcID|EpisodeDate|ProcID|EpisodeDate|ProcID|EpisodeDate|ProcID

SKREE|B20190531064919932|20-May-19|5A1955Z|20-May-19|0BH17EZ|24-May-19|03HY32Z|6-Jun-19|03HY32Z|21-May-19|02HV33Z|21-May-19|B548ZZA
```

Thanks!

Comment: whats your database? why do you want a query like this? I don't know what have you planned with that output, but in a first sight seems quite messy to be useful

Comment: This will obviously require some dynamic SQL, you probably won't get any solutions without tagging your specific database.

Comment: Hi, using SQL Server 13. We are putting a view together for the Visits as they are used over dozens of reports, and we want to make sure everyone is pulling the same procedures. Most of our datafeed request specifications have dictated that the output be done that way.

Comment: I assume NULL is ok where there are fewer total values, also I couldn't match any deterministic sort order to your sample output, so I just ordered by `SortOrder` since, well, it sounds like that's what that column should be for.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic PIVOTs are fun, there are definitely some different approaches to finding the limit. Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT SourceID, VisitID';

;WITH x AS /* how many pivots do we need? */
(
  SELECT TOP 1 c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Visits 
  GROUP BY SourceID, VisitID ORDER BY c DESC
),
n(n) AS /* produce that many rows for dynamic SQL */ 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < (SELECT c FROM x)
)
SELECT @sql += N', 
  EpisodeDate' + CONVERT(varchar(11), n) + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' 
               + CONVERT(varchar(11), n) + N' THEN EpisodeDate END),
  ProcID'      + CONVERT(varchar(11), n) + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' 
               + CONVERT(varchar(11), n) + N' THEN ProcID END)' 
FROM n OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767); -- in case you go beyond 100

SET @sql += N' FROM src 
GROUP BY SourceID, VisitID;';

SET @sql = N'
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT SourceID, VisitID, EpisodeDate, ProcID, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SourceID, VisitID ORDER BY SortOrder)
  FROM dbo.Visits
)
' + @sql;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- [Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2f52461bcf08a177acc414ec7bb381da)
- [Article for more background](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: That is fantastic. Works like a charm!
I didn't think of counting the episodes to calculate the rows

I added EpisodeUrnID to cut down the number of columns, as there were lots of blanks at the end when I ran it against the whole database

SELECT TOP 1 c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Visits 
  GROUP BY SourceID, VisitID, EpisodeUrnID ORDER BY c DESC

Comment: Can you think of a way to add the SortOrder number to each column name, so each set of dates & procedures increment?

Comment: @user16800054 Update should do it.

Comment: You da bomb! That works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: One last question... any ideas on how to create a view from this?
I tried to create a View, but cannot because of the declare statement.
Would I need to use a Parameterized view with Inline User Defined functions?

Comment: @desertdude You can't use dynamic SQL in a view or in a function. I would pursue changing whatever code thinks it needs to consume a view to be able to consume the output of a stored procedure.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. I "dumbed" it down a bit, and I can put this in a View.  It's not dynamic, but we will account for up to 50 episodes, which should be more than enough

Comment: 'src AS   
(
    SELECT  SourceID, VisitID, EpisodeDate, ProcID, ProcName, Surgeon,Specialty 
       ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SourceID, VisitID, EpisodeUrnID ORDER BY SortOrder)    
    FROM RD  
)
SELECT SourceID, VisitID   
,               EpisodeDate1= MAX(CASE WHEN rn =1 THEN EpisodeDate END)
,               ProcID1= MAX(CASE WHEN rn =1 THEN ProcID END)
,               EpisodeDate2= MAX(CASE WHEN rn =2 THEN EpisodeDate END)
,               ProcID2= MAX(CASE WHEN rn =2 THEN ProcID END)
FROM   src  
GROUP BY  SourceID, VisitID;'